# How to log out of a chrome.identity oauth2.0 token

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm using Google Oauth with chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken(). I could sign in the user, but not sign out using removeCachedAuthToken().

```
 chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({ token: current_token },
        function() {});
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +current_token);
      xhr.send();
```

Is there any way to clear the logged in state of the chrome.identity plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need that

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
{ 'url': 'https://accounts.google.com/logout' },
function(tokenUrl) {
    responseCallback();
}
```

);

Comment: Here what is the responseCallback() method?

Comment: that's a method you create for the callback function to redirect for ex

Comment: can you give me some example

Comment: you can comment it

Comment: you just check the response JSON attr if you wanna do something with them

Comment: Thank you, i got something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168032/discussion-between-mahendra-and-mooga).